# Minkowski Honeycombs

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

What are the honeycombs (tessellations) of Minkowski space? Would like to know at least the isochoric/cell-transitive/"space filling" ones, but a complete list of regular ones would be nice.

Honeycombs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeycomb_(geometry)

Minkowski Space: A space with metric signature <-1,1,1,1>

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that other users will know exactly what the issue here is.

Comment: After the edit, I still fail to understand what is being asked (aren't they simply the same ones one would get for $\mathbb{R}^4$?) or how it relates to Physics (apart from the fact that Minkowski spacetime has applications in Physics).

Comment: @NickolasAlves: *aren't they simply the same ones one would get for $\mathbb{R}^4$?* I assume OP is interested in “cells” that are congruent to one another by an action of Poincare group element, as opposed to $ISO(4)$

Comment: @A.V.S. Yes that is what I'm asking.